# PDE characterisation of elementary symmetric functions?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, symmetric-polynomials

For $k\leq{}n$ the elementary symmetric polynomials are defined by:
$$e_k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{1\leq{}i_1<...<i_k\leq{}n}x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_k}$$
I believe I can prove (by a complex brute force method) that the function:
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=e_k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)/(x_1+\cdots+x_n)^k$$
satisfies the following PDE:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial{}{x_i}^2}\right)+k(k-1)f=0$$
I have some questions, since both symmetric polynomials and PDEs are out of my area:

1. Is the above (assuming it is correct) known or easily proven, e.g. is there a reference I could use or a relatively simple proof?
2. Does PDE theory tell us anything about uniqueness of solutions of the given PDE(s)?

Thanks

Helmut

Comment: I think ultimately many symmetric polynomials can be obtained as eigenfunctions of Laplace-Beltrami operators; see for instance page 9 of http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/73.pdf discusses this for Jack polynomials; for elementary symmetric polynomials, this may simplify / specialize.

Answer (score 7):

For your first question, here's a simple proof.

1. Observe that $\partial_{ii}^2 e_k = 0$ for any $i\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$. This implies 
   $$ \partial^2_{ii} (\sigma^k f) = 0 \tag{1}$$
   for any $i$, where $\sigma = \sum x_i$.
2. Observe that 
   $$ \partial_i \sigma = 1 $$
   for any $i$, and hence 
   $$ \partial_i \sigma^k = k \sigma^{k-1} \tag{2}$$
   by the chain rule.
3. The product rule applied to (1) using (2) gives
   $$ 0 = k(k-1)\sigma^{k-2} f + 2 k \sigma^{k-1} \partial_i f + \sigma^k \partial^2_{ii} f$$
   from which we divide by $\sigma^k$ to obtain
   $$ \partial^2_{ii} f + k(k-1)\sigma^{-2} f + 2 k \sigma^{-1} \partial_i f = 0 \tag{3}$$
   Recall that this holds *individually for any $i$*.
4. Multiply now the expression (3) by $x_i$. And sum over $i$, we get finally
   $$ \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \partial^2_{ii} f + k(k-1) \sigma^{-2} f \underbrace{\sum x_i}_{= \sigma} + 2 k \sigma^{-1} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i \partial_i f = 0 \tag{4} $$
5. Now observe that $f$ is, by definition, a [homogeneous function of degree 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function). So the homogeneous derivative $\sum x_i \partial_i f = 0$. This kills the last term in (4). The remainder is exactly what you wanted to show.

---

Concerning uniqueness, observe that only two ingredients were used in the derivation of the PDE above:

1. That the original function $e_k$ satisfies $\partial^2_{ii} e_k = 0$ for any $i$.
2. That the original function $e_k$ is homogeneous of degree $k$.

There are a lot more functions that satisfy the same property. For example, when $n = 3$ and $k = 2$, we know that it works for $e_k = x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_3 + x_3 x_1$. But the same also works for $x_1 x_2$ or $x_2 x_3$ or $x_3 x_1$ or any linear combination thereof.